# Selecting All filtered objects in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using custom Angular filter to filter out required objects from an array.All works well .I have provided checkbox against each object to select that object.And also a SELECT ALL CHECKBOX to select filtered objects.So problem arises when selecting all as I cant get these filtered objects back in JS.

Comment: Could you please add a little code in here.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, But I think you could name the filtered result and use that array in your controller:

Option 1

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in (itemsSelected = (items | filter: checkbox))">
   {{item}}
 </div>
```

Option 2

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items  | filter:checkbox as itemsSelected ">
   {{item}}
 </div>
```

Then in your controller you will have this property available, which represents the filtered result.

```
$scope.itemsSelected
```